# Android Kotlin Extension super calling

Tags: kotlin, super, kotlin-android-extensions, kotlin-extension

i am a Java Android Developer and i'm approaching to Kotlin

I have defined the following class:

```
open class Player : RealmObject() {
    ...
}
```

And i defined the following two extensions, one for the generic RealmObject class and one for the specific Player class:

```
fun RealmObject.store() {
    Realm.getDefaultInstance().use { realm ->
        realm.beginTransaction()
        realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(this)
        realm.commitTransaction()
    }
}

fun Player.store(){
    this.loggedAt = Date()
    (this as RealmObject).store()
}
```

What i want is if i call `.store()` on any `RealmObject` object, the `RelamObject.store()` extension will be called BUT if i call `.store()` on a `Player` instance the extension that will be called will be `Player.store()`.
(No problem for now)
I don't want to copy paste the same code, i love to write less reuse more.
So i need that internally the `Player.store()` will call the generic `RealmObject.store()`

I got it. The code i wrote up there is actually working as expected :D

What i am asking is (just because i wrote that just by personally intuition):

**Is this the good way?! Or there is some better way?**

Thank you

Comment: If the code works properly and what you want is a code review or a better way of doing this task, you should go to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and post this doubt there.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach seems to be perfectly correct, because it does exactly what is needed. Kotlin resolves the extension calls based on the [**static**](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extensions-are-resolved-statically) (inferred or declared) type of the receiver expression, and the cast `(this as RealmObject)` makes the static expression type `RealmObject`.

Another valid way to do this, which I'm not sure is better, is to use a callable reference to the other extension:

```
fun Player.store(){
    this.loggedAt = Date()
    (RealmObject::store)(this)
}
```